# Swift: URL extension causing a crash when called

Tags: ios, swift, url, extension-methods

I wrote this extension for the `URL` class

```
extension URL {
        var appendAppParams:  URL {
            let extention_A: String = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: SOME_KEY) ?? ""
            let extention_B: String = "SOME_VALUE"
        
       //The crash happen in the next line of code
        if self.absoluteString.contains("SOME_STRING") && !(self.absoluteString.contains(URL.KEY_1)) {
            return self.appendItem(key: URL.KEY_1, value: SOME_STRING)
        }
        
        var url = self
        if !url.absoluteString.contains(URL.KEY_1) {
            url = url.appendItem(key: URL.KEY_1, value: SOME_VALUE)
        }
        
        if !url.absoluteString.contains(SOME_KEY){
            url = url.appendItem(key:SOME_KEY, value: SOME_VALUE)
        }
        
        return url
    }
}
```

`appendItem` is another extension for `URL` class

```
extension URL {
func appendItem(key: String, value: String)-> URL {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString)!
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)]
    if let originalParams = urlComponents.queryItems {
        queryItems.append(contentsOf: originalParams)
    }
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    return urlComponents.url!
}
```

}

```
extension URL {
    static let KEY_1 = "SOME_VALUE"
}
```

The crash prints to the console:

```
    *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x106922cc8 of class 'Swift._SwiftObject' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector +[Swift._SwiftObject absoluteString]
2020-12-18 17:42:55.220568+0200 APP_NAME Unrecognized selector +[Swift._SwiftObject absoluteString]
```

How I'm I calling the extension?

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
let webURLString = webView.url?.absoluteString ?? ""
if (!(webURLString.contains(URL.KEY_1))){
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            redirectTo(urlStr: webURLString)
            return
        }
}
func redirectTo(urlStr: String){
        if let url = URL(string: urlStr) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                let urlWithAppParams = url.appendAppParams
                request = URLRequest(url: urlWithAppParams)
                self.webView.load(request)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apparently you have a custom class `URL` Rename it, it clashes with Foundation struct `URL`.

Comment: @vadian I do not have any custom URL class.

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach anyway. You can use `URLComponents` and the `queryItems` property rather than trying to manipulate the URL directly in this way.

Comment: @Paulw11 I’m using URLComponents and queryItems, can you give an example so I can understand your suggestion well?

Comment: Rather than extending URL it would be better to have some "factory" method that creates your URL, using `URLComponents` "from scratch".  However, in regard to your crash, can you show how you are invoking the extension?

Comment: @Paulw11 Simply calling url.appendAppParams

Comment: Yes,  but where did `url` come from? The exception message indicates that the object that this extension is being called on doesn't have an `absoluteString` method and isn't an instance of `URL`.

Comment: @Paulw11 I added that to my question You can check it

Comment: It is a weird problem. Have you tried just implementing the code as a function. To be honest I don't see any real reason to use an extension here.

Comment: @Paulw11 what worked for now is turning the appendAppParams parameter to a function in the URL class. So now I'm calling 
`url.appendAppParams()`

I will keep this question opened to see if anyone might be able to clarify what happened.